# Do Inuit leaders have enough sovereignty to allow China to build infrastructure for them in Canada?

Tags: china, canada, inuit

> The Canadian Security Intelligence Service (CSIS) has warned Inuit
> leaders that foreign adversaries could gain a foothold in Canada by
> offering to fill infrastructure gaps in the North.
>
> But Natan Obed, president of the Inuit Tapiriit Kanatami (ITK) — the
> nonprofit organization that represents more than 65,000 Inuit across
> Inuit Nunangat and the rest of Canada — **said the spy agency's
> inability to share classified intelligence with the region's
> decision-makers leaves them in the dark about the risks.**
>
> **"We are making decisions every day that are currently not as informed
> as they could be about threats and considerations," Obed recently told
> CBC News.**
>
> "The partners that we choose are sometimes not the partners that we
> hope to have."

https://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/csis-arctic-obed-russia-china-1.6993128

Do Inuit leaders have enough sovereignty to allow China to build infrastructure for them in Canada? The article seems to suggest that they have enough authority, but after doing some research I couldn't find anything that confirms it.

Comment: At the very least the Federal government could just deny visas to the Chinese workers or deport any that are already in the country.

Comment: @JonathanReez Canada would want to maintain polite relationship with China. Deporting Chinese workers based on previously agreed plan is impolite so Canada is trying to act coherently.

Comment: I think you're slightly misleading that. It's not an issue of (Inuit) sovereignty but everyday business decision making. There have been similar concerns raised in the US that the local businesses may have no idea who in China controls some company that decides to do business in the US. It's because federal agencies generally have secrecy rules that prevent them sharing that info with the "peons" https://www.nytimes.com/2023/10/03/business/gotion-chinese-subsidiary-michigan-protests.html

Comment: Or https://edition.cnn.com/2022/07/23/politics/fbi-investigation-huawei-china-defense-department-communications-nuclear/index.html

Comment: @Fizz of course, the Huawei ”threat” was mostly in the imagination of government officials, not a real threat. The nice thing about being in the intelligence service is that you don’t have to justify your decisions to voters.

Comment: @Fizz Hmmm, not entirely true.  Yes, local businesses can end up fronting for China, willingly or unwillingly.  But First Nations/Inuit territories in Canada, are, in some ways, self-governing and can bypass national laws (for example, there's been talk of for-profit healthcare on reserves, something 200% against BC provincial laws).   However, the status of many nations embedded within larger nations (say Monaco in France) explicitly delegates *foreign affairs* to their host country.  Whereas Italy BRI-ed a while back.  How First Nations/Inuit status affects China influence is of interest.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: the Q quotes something about an NGO. NGOs don't have that kind of power. Sure some other Inuit structures might.